Is there a reason 24.04 LTS Noble Numbat does not provide libglut.so.3?
Previous versions of Ubuntu (e.g. Focal & Jammy) provided the libglut.so.3 file with the freeglut3 package. It looks like 24.04 has done away with that package, and now provides the libglut3.12 package instead.
However, the libglut3.12 and libglut-dev packages only provide the .so file under the libglut.so, libglut.so.3.12 and libglut.so.3.12.0 names. Missing is the libglut.so.3 name that was previously provided by the freeglut3 package.
Is there a reason for the lack of this name? Is libglut 3.12 not compatible with the libglut 3 provided with freeglut?
I ask because we have a piece of third-party code which is expecting libglut.so.3 to be provided in the system libraries, and which was working fine under Focal & Jammy. One would hope that it could be made to work on 24.04 without recompiling. Is this possible?

Just add the link yourself with sudo, does look like something was forgotten in the package, but easy to fix.

Do you know how to create a symlink?
